# multimensionnal hash table - perl

Tags: perl, hash, key-value

my hash table looks like that:

```
$VAR1 = \{
    'Good night , she said softly .' => {
        'tokens_en' => [
            'Good',
            'night',
            ',',
            'she',
            'said',
            'softly',
            '.'
        ],
        'tokens_fr' => [
            'word_fr_1',
            'word_fr_2',
            'word_fr_1'                                                   
        ],
        'score' => '0.270968',
        'sentence' => 'word_fr_1 word_fr_2 word_fr_3 .'
    }
};
```

Now i need to add information to the value corresponding to "tokens_en" in the hash table like that:

```
$VAR1 = \{
    'Good night , she said softly .' => {
        'tokens_en' => [
            'Good'   => [a,b,c],
            'night',
            ',',
            'she'    => [d,e,f],
            'said'   => [g,h,i],
            'softly' => [k,l,m],
            '.'
        ],
```

How can i do that using, I've tried this code but does'nt work:

```
$hash->{sentence1}->{tokens_en}{\@tokens_en} = \@tokens_test;
```

The tables with the values [a,b,c] and [d,e,f] etc. are created in an other step.

Comment: Why `$hash->{sentence1}->{tokens_en}{\@tokens_en} = \@tokens_test;`? How about `$hash->{sentence1}->{tokens_en} = \@tokens_test;`?

Comment: What command did you use to dump the hash? `$VAR1 = \{ ... };` is very weird

Comment: `[ 'Good', [ 'word1', 'word2', ], 'night', ',', ... ]`? Your desired format makes little sense.

Comment: Finally, what you are trying to achieve is unclear.

Comment: sorry I've clarify the initial question. In fact, the new informations [a,b,c] are totally different from [word1,word2,word3]. I want to associate an array of strings to each string of tokens_en. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Seems the OP decided to post his edited question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027546/create-a-hash-table-with-keys-from-an-array-table-perl).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but maybe we can get there slowly.

Starting with your original data structure, you want to change the value for the `tokens_en` key from an anonymous array (that's the square braces `[...]` ) to an anonymous hash so each word that was in the array is now a key in that hash.

This gives me a chance to use [Perl v5.20's experimental postfix dereferencing](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/):

```
use v5.20;
use feature qw(postderef);
no warnings qw(experimental::postderef);


my $outer_hash = {
        'Good night , she said softly .' => {
                                            'tokens_en' => [
                                                             'Good',
                                                             'night',
                                                             ',',
                                                             'she',
                                                             'said',
                                                             'softly',
                                                             '.'
                                                           ],
                                            'tokens_fr' => [
                                                             'word1',
                                                             'word2',
                                                             'word3'                                                   
                                                           ],
                                            'score' => '0.270968',
                                            'sentence' => 'word1 word2 word3 .'
                                          }

      };

foreach my $sentence ( keys %$outer_hash ) {
    # the inner reference, for easier typing and shorter lines
    my $inner_hash = $outer_hash->{ $sentence };


    # get all the words in the inner array  
    # http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/
    my @tokens_en = $inner_hash->{ 'tokens_en' }->@*;
    # before v5.20, use:
    # my @tokens_en = @{ $inner_hash->{ 'tokens_en' } }

    # make the new value, which will be a hash
    # how do you determine the values in there?
    my %tokens_en_hash = map { $_, [ qw(some words ???) ] } @tokens_en;

    # set the new value 
    $inner_hash->{ 'tokens_en' } = \%tokens_en_hash;

    # delete the keys you don't need anymore
    delete @$inner_hash{ qw(tokens_fr score sentence) };
    }

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper( $outer_hash );
```

I don't know how you want to select the values to be in the array that each word points to, so you'll have to clarify that.