# Create a Hash table with keys from an array table - perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

How can i create a hash table with keys coming from an array table ?

I've got this array: `my @array = ("car","bus","bike")`;

and I need to have a hash like that:

```
my %h = ( "car" => "1",
      "bus" => "2",
      "bike" => "3" );
```

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash slice to populate it with keys/values,

```
my @array = ("car","bus","bike");
my %h;
@h{@array} = 1 .. @array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the indexes of the array.

```
my %h;
for (0..$#array) {
   $h{ $array[$_] } = $_ + 1;
}
```

That can be shortened to

```
my %h = map { $array[$_] => $_+1 } 0..$#array;
```